# Annotate a django field

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add some extra arguments to a field definition so I can parse that at a later time, such as:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=40, something='yes')
```

Later on:

```
for field_obj in Item._meta.fields[1:]: # ignore auto-pk
    field = field_obj.name
    something = field_obj.annotations['something']
    print (field, something)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an attribute after defining the field

```
class Item(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    field.something = 'yes'
```

Then it should be available on the field

```
Item._meta.get_field('field').something
```